# If in a orthogonal basis of a Hilbert space H, i take off just one element, do i get a strict subpsace of H?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $B=\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of orthogonal elements of $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with $b_n \neq 0$

Let $A=B\setminus \{b_1\}$

I wolud like to know if is it true that:

$$
\overline{
\operatorname{span}
A
}
\subsetneq
\overline{
\operatorname{span}
B
}
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the $b_n$ are nonzero then yes, since $b_1$ is orthogonal
to $\overline{\textrm{span}\,A}$.

Comment: thanks @LordSharktheUnknown , now i edited that $b_n \neq 0$ and thanks for your answer